# Blurry font in JTextArea

Tags: java, fonts, jtextarea, blurry

I have downloaded the gohu font (which is programmer font meant to be used at 14pt) from here  https://github.com/koemaeda/gohufont-ttf and I'm trying to display some text with it.

This is what it looks like in GIMP at 14pt (nice and sharp):

[image: ok at 14pt in gimp]

And now this is what I get when loading the font using PLAIN 14 in a JTextArea:

[image: blurry in JTextArea]

I've tried disabling anti aliasing with

```
((Graphics2D)(this.displayArea.getGraphics())).setRenderingHint(RenderingHints.KEY_TEXT_ANTIALIASING, RenderingHints.VALUE_TEXT_ANTIALIAS_OFF);
```

and

```
System.setProperty("awt.useSystemAAFontSettings","false");
```

but it didn't help. Any tips?
Thanks

Comment: The first line of code won't work because `getGraphics()` returns brand new Graphics object each time it's called.  I suspect this can only be solved by overriding the TextUI and the View, which is going to be ugly.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. Is there really no other way though? Basically what you're saying is that using non-antialiased fonts in java is a no go? :(

Comment: I ran a simple painting test and confirmed that the problem isn't Java;  a straight graphics.drawString call uses the font's hints and draws text exactly as GIMP does.  After some more searching, I happened upon [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4805833/how-can-i-force-one-specific-jtextarea-to-not-use-anti-aliasing-while-keeping-i/4806023#4806023), which works perfectly—though the use of sun.* classes is at your own risk, since they are always subject to change or removal in future releases.

Comment: Thanks, I tried this.displayArea.putClientProperty(sun.swing.SwingUtilities2.AA_TEXT_PROPERTY_KEY, null); but I can't compile:- Access restriction: The field 'SwingUtilities2.AA_TEXT_PROPERTY_KEY' is not API (restriction on required library '/xxx/jdk1.8.0_25/jre/lib/
  rt.jar')
 - Access restriction: The type 'SwingUtilities2' is not API (restriction on required library '/xxx/jdk1.8.0_25/jre/lib/rt.jar')

Comment: That sounds like an Eclipse issue.  (It works for me on the command line, using Java 1.7.0_72 and 1.8.0_25.)  Perhaps [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9266632/access-restriction-is-not-accessible-due-to-restriction-on-required-library), [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/860187/access-restriction-on-class-due-to-restriction-on-required-library-rt-jar) or [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1089904/access-restriction-on-class-due-to-restriction-on-required-library) will help?